# Filled contour plot with R (ggplot) - depth profile of temperature over time -

Tags: r, time, contour, depth, temperature

I'm relatively new to R and have a dataset of about 60 points in time, where temperature was measured between 0.3 and 18 m water depth. The purpose is to create a contour plot preferably with ggplot2 that reflects the high resolution over time (x = days, y = depth, z = temperature). 
I tried several approaches using:

ggplot + geom_tile

contour plot

ggplot + stat_contour

filled.contour

but some of them I didn't manage to work and the others didn't obtain the desired result (pixelated contours or only lines without possibility to fill the gaps).

**Data file:** http://www.filedropper.com/budgetcontourf

**Example how it should look like:** [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjPJs.png)

**This is what I have achieved so far:** *I couldn't post more than 2 links. Using the code below will show the result anyways.*

Looking forward to your suggestions or solutions! Thanks a lot in advance!!

PS.: There is probably also a better way to deal with the problem of R renaming the headings of the columns during 'import dataset' (numbers were renamed, e.g. 2 to X2).

```
#                           +++ CONTOUR PLOT +++

#load dataset manually

# load packages
library(ggplot2) 

#Renames the colums 
colnames(budget_contour_F) <- c('depth', '-2',  '-1',   '0',    '1',    '2',
'3',    '5',    '7',    '8',    '9',    '11',   '13',   '15',   '17',   '19',
'21',   '23',   '25',   '27',   '29',   '31',   '33',   '35',   '37',   '39',
'41',   '43',   '45',   '47',   '49',   '51',   '53',   '55',   '57',   '59',
'61',   '63',   '65',   '67',   '69',   '71',   '73',   '75',   '77',   '79',
'81',   '83',   '85',   '87',   '89',   '91',   '93',   '95',   '97',   '99',
'101',  '103')

#Melt data
CPF <- melt(budget_contour_F, id=c("depth"))

#Renames the colums
colnames(CPF) <- c('depth', 'day', 'temp')

#Contour colour only
ggplot(CPF, aes(x = day, y = depth, z = temp)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = temp)) + 
  stat_contour() +
  scale_y_reverse(name="depth (m)") +
  theme_bw()

#Contour lines only
contourplot(temp ~ day * depth, data = CPF)
```